# Some videos have no thumbnail?

Tags: nautilus, video, thumbnails, mp4

I just downloaded a video series and opened the videos folder to find that some of the videos have thumbnails and some do not. How can I force the others to generate thumbnails?
I have tried playing the videos with out thumbnails but they did not generate; I also tried renaming them, but no luck.

All videos are mp4 and play fine.
I did tell Ubuntu when installing to install 3rd party codecs etc.

Comment: Which application handle the thumbnail generation, `totem` or `ffmpegthumbailner`?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the thumbnail cache by typing this in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -r $HOME/.thumbnails/fail
sudo rm -r $HOME/.thumbnails/normal
```

Close any Nautilus window and now check your video series.

Comment: there is no need for the *sudo* command. Everything is working on the user level. Btw, this didn't worked for me.